# fireEvent inside a menu Listener errors

Tags: extjs, scope, dom-events, extjs3

```
return new Ext.Button({
  text: cfg.text,
  menu: {
    xtype: 'menu',
    items: cfg.menu,
    listeners: {
      itemclick: {
        fn: function() {
          console.log(this);
          this.fireEvent('tabchange', 'apps');
        },
        scope: this
      },
      scope: this
    },
    scope: this
  },
  minWidth: 50,
  scope: this
});
```

cfg comes as a parameter to the function. It's all there.
Console.log works - therefor code up until that point works as well.
The this does seem to be in the right scope.

Yet the fireEvent ends up with:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Following the calls in the error log, fireEvent does get executed, it reaches

```
EXTUTIL.Event.fire
 if(l && l.fireFn.apply(l.scope || me.obj || window, args) === FALSE)
```

Is where it fails.

Is there some kind of scoping/ nesting issue when trying to call an event inside event listener?

My goal is to trigger that event on a menu item selection for the button.

Comment: Did you check the scope(this) using break points??

Comment: if i specifically added scope on each step, the scope can  still end up wrong?
If i didn't add the scope: this - i simply end up getting fireEvent undefined.
I can access other variables, functions through this aswell.

I assume the fireEvent somehow is still out of scope when looking for the custom event in that class and cant find it.
The events are  set as  this.addEvents() in the initComponent.

And breakpoint on  the fireEvent does show proper looking scope on this - and that event is listed.

Comment: AH - debugging through by steps, it seems like one of the listeners is undefined. Which still puzzles me - as that very same event works fine if its in a diff buttons handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was due to a undefined handler.

The handler was set  using

> this.on()

in initComponent before superclass init.